# View video at any angle

Tags: 3d-view, video

How can I see a video loaded in the background at any angle?
not only in the view of the camera or left right up down

Comment: do you mean like a poster always positioned exactly in the background regardless of angle or do you mean panorama that is sky box surrounding your scene?

Comment: I mean a rectangular background regardless of the angle, not a panorama

Comment: Render with a transparent background then in the Composistor add and image input node and Alpha Over node. Set the Image node file to your movie.  You can also render everything to transparent PNG sequence and then use the VSE to do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

Without using additional geometry or compositing, you can use the image as background for the world. Set the Texture coordinates to Window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but if you are looking to view your object at different angles, press down on your scroll wheel and you should be able to see at all different angles.